# Hiding URL variables/values in a query string. PHP

Tags: php, encryption, password-protection

What's the best way to hide variables and their values in a query string when passing it to the server? I have done a lot of research and still can't find an optimal solution. Sending them by GET method shows the variables in the network activity tab (google chrome), and sending them by POST also shows them in the network send headers.

I have also considered encrypting them, but since the encryption is done on the frontend it would be easy for somebody to get the encryption seed/key and decrypt the information (not to mention it would be heavy on the server to decrypt every call).

Comment: have you considered SSL?

Comment: You could hash it client side before it sends. https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5

Comment: Never roll your own crypto, ever. Use proper and well established security protocols and read the OWASP guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

In short: [Don't encrypt URL parameters, use a separate look-up](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

Also, using HTTPS is basically non-negotiable if you desire any measure of web application security. It should be treated as mandatory in 2019. Get comfortable with TLS 1.2+.

---

#### What developers want to do

[image: What developers want to do]

#### What developers should do instead

[image]